# How to set up JBoss 6.4 EAP with IBM Websphere MQueue using database configuration

Tags: java, database, jboss, ibm-mq

I have a JBoss 6.4 EAP and a Websphere MQueue. The JBoss needs to receive messages using Message-Driven beans from the Websphere MQueue. Is there an existing library/a programmable way to let the JBoss connect to Queues where the configuration parameters of the queues and queue manager are in an oracle database? I know of the [Websphere MQ Resource adapter](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Deploy_the_WebSphere_MQ_Resource_Adapter.html) but want to have the configuration in the database. This is due to organisational and access reasons.

Answer (score 1):

JBoss does not have a mechanism to fetch configuration information from a database.  Having configuration properties as java system properties is supported.  JBoss also has a configuration "vault" to store properties.

- Doug